# How display and image matching the width but extending the height below the screen in a recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, imageview

I'm trying to display an image with a dimension like 700x2000 and I would like it to match the width of the screen and expand below the screen like in the [image: screenshot].

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/comic_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
```

This is my current image item used as template and doesn't work, what I'm trying to achieve is make the red square match the width and extends it's height based on the image height, the yellow part is the rest of the image that's hidden and shown when scrolling. I can't get how to achieve this, it's a xml problem because the one below kinda works but displays the whole image in the screen and it's small

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/comic_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to use all the different types of scaleType or use a different parent for the image but none worked